# Redirect after login when WordPress in subdirectory

Tags: redirect, login, htaccess, directory, wp-login-form

I've a problem in my Wordpress website which is after I login from `/wp-admin` I didn't redirected to anywhere just keep seeing the login page without any errors.

it was working fine when the site was on the root directory but now it stopped working.

I used the `.htaccess` found here https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

but it still no redirecting to the dashboard.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you also have a **copy** of `index.php` (from WordPress root) in the *new* root together with your `.htaccess` file, which which has as last line `require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/my_subdir/wp-blog-header.php' );`. You could also add in   `wp-config.php` 2 lines: `define('WP_HOME', 'http://example.com');` and `define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/my_subdir');` as extra maybe that helps also. *If that works all together please don't forget to go to *Settings/Permalinks* (in admin panel) and click *Save Changes*.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me